# Print a specific area of webpage with highlighted content

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Ive redone some of the code and tried this, but my print function doesn't work. If it got working would this only print the div id example?

```
<div id='example'>
<h3>Saturday Sept. 8th</h3>

</p><strong>7:00AM-8:00AM</strong> </p>
<input type="radio" name= "one" /><label> meditation meeting</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name= "one" <label> step 1 workshop</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name= "one"<label > Bottom lines</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name= "one"<label > Top Lines</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name= "one"<label> Sponsorship</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name= "one"<label> Being a Sponsee</label>
<br>
<br> 
</p> <strong>8:15AM-9:15AM</strong></p>
<input type="radio" name= "two"<label> Step 2 workshop</label>
<br> 
<input type="radio" name= "two"<label>Living life</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name= "two"<label> chairing a meeting</label>
<br> 
<input type="radio" name= "two"<label>Service work</label>
<br> 
<input type="radio" name= "two"<label> Accepting gifts</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name= "two"<label>Principles before Personalities</label> 
<br>
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="printPage('example');"></input>

</div>
```

Comment: What's the problem you are having?

Comment: First of all "an attendee can select various activities" This means you want CheckBoxes not radiobuttons

Comment: Im using radio buttons as attendees can only select one activity per time frame, my issue is that I want the "schedule" to be printed, not the whole web page.

Comment: Clarified author intent. You should mention whether you want the selection to be highlighted ONLY in print, or both in print and live when making the selection. Also, the `for` attribute is only useful if your `<input>` has a *unique* `id` (in the snippet above it doesnt)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the for attribute. I would like the selected items to be highlighted amongst the program schedule when it gets printed, this would also be understood by the radio buttons being highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control printing in the web browser because that's a user-end functionality, so a workaround/hackie way is required, what I usually do is the following:

You can make a di that will appear in the middle of the screen covering everything behind it using the `z-index` property

And then fill it with desired content to be printed

And then Right-click==>Print

And then on the printing dialog you can resize the printed content as needed.

Comment: I appreciate your comments but I think it's a little out of my league. Im a real beginner.

Comment: Practice makes perfect.

Comment: Isn't it possible to put a "tag" in front of the schedule I want printed, and one in the end, then print that "tag"?